# Websync 4.0 - Publisher async

Tags: .net, asynchronous, websync

Is there a way of using Websync Publisher asynchronously?
Currently I'm doing this

```
var publisher = new Publisher(url);
var result = publisher.Publish(publication);
if (!result.Successful)
    //Log exception
```

The problem with this version is that when making the first **Publish** it takes somewhere around 2 seconds.
I saw on some forums that in earlier versions of Websync they offered the possibility of using **Publisher** asynchronously [see here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/websync/1uIiodIvP-E), but for some reason that's not available in Websync 4.0

I've tried publishing asynchronously like this

```
var publisher = new Publisher(url);
Func<Publication> a = () => Publisher.Publish(publication);
a.BeginInvoke(result =>
{
    var m = result.AsyncState as Func<Publication>;
    if (m != null)
    {
        var asyncResult = m.EndInvoke(result);
        if (!asyncResult.Successful)
            // Log exception
    }
 }, a);
```

But this resulted in a "null reference" exception on

```
var asyncResult = m.EndInvoke(result);
```

which I couldn't really reproduce in development.

Any ideas on how to better approach this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code on a thread-pool thread:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
{
    var publisher = new Publisher(url);
    var result = publisher.Publish(publication);
    if (!result.Successful)
        //Log exception
}, null);
```

It's short-lived, so you can use a thread from the CLR thread-pool.